# 'where' in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
df:

-----------+
|       word|
+-----------+
|       1609|
|           |
|        the|
|    sonnets|
|           |
|         by|
|    william|
|shakespeare|
|           |
|         fg|
```

This is my data frame. How to remove the empty rows (to remove the rows that contain '') using the 'where' clause.

```
code:

df.where(trim(df.word) == "").show()

output:

----+
|word|
+----+
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trim and check if result is empty:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import trim
>>> df.where(trim(df.word) != "")
```

Comment: thanks for the time. The solution did not work. It made all the rows in the data frame empty. I will update the question part to show the result.

Comment: Sorry, typo in operator.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from **where**, you can also use **filter** to achieve this.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import trim

df.filter(trim(df.word) != "").show()

df.where(trim(df.word) != "").show()
```